# Why is python if condition not working for values of "False"?

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean, boolean-expression

In the following code, `is_number` is **False** for the value `"foo"`, but this still prints `is a number` for that string. Why? And how do I fix it?

```
def string_is_number(a_string):
    pattern = re.compile(r'[0-9]+')
    if pattern.search(a_string):
        return("True")
    else:
        return("False")
 
for value in 42, 0.5, "foo":
    the_string = str(value)
    is_number = string_is_number(the_string)
    print(the_string, is_number)
    if is_number:
        print(the_string, "is a number")
```

Output:

```
42 True
42 is a number
0.5 True
0.5 is a number
foo False
foo is a number
```

Comment: That function returns a string, not a boolean

Comment: Your regex also matches "lkjh456uzt"

Comment: Instead of `string_is_number` that returns "True" if there are any digits in the string, consider dumping that function completely and just using `the_string.isdigit()`.

Comment: How accurate does your "is a number" check need to be? 6,381 is a normal way to write numbers. But what about 6,33,1? Is that a number? 12:22?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return a `bool`, not a `str`:

```
if pattern.search(a_string):
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Any non-empty string in Python is considered true (or "truthy"), including `"False"`:

```
>>> bool("False")
True
```

Then of course, the regex for your number detection is a bit off:

```
re.match("^\d+([.,]\d+)?$", a_string)
```

would be a tighter test.

Comment: I like your answer but part of the fix is to ditch the regex completely because it only tests if the string has a digit, not is a number. `str.isdigit()` is a good replacement.

Comment: It is not really part of the question though. "1,23" or "1.23" should be considered numbers as I take it, so `str.isdigit` won't be enough

Comment: ...except maybe not. Just realized there are commas in there.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to return "True" and "False" as string. You need to return them as boolean like this:

```
def string_is_number(a_string):
    
    pattern = re.compile(r'[0-9]+')
    
    return pattern.search(a_string) # Returns True or False
```

Comment: We can try a lot, but would you mind explaining whether it works and why it works?

Answer (score 0):

Your function failed because you returned non-empty strings, which are always`True`. A more subtle problem is that you call anything that has at least one digit a number. So "I am not the number 1" is a number. A nice way to check if something is a "number" is to try to convert it. In your case, it looks like you are dealing with integers and floats which both can be converted to `float`. Because commas are not allowed in string literals, they need to be factored out, but your function could be

```
def string_is_number(a_string):
    try:
        float(a_string.strip(','))
        return True
    except:
        return False
```